# Detect java applet modal dialog in webbrowser control

Tags: java, .net, applet, webbrowser-control

We are hosting web applications in a .Net webbrowser control embedded in a winform.

When a java applet in a web application displays a modal dialog, only the applet area within the webapplication is deactivated. (The requirement is firefox-style modality).

Is there a way to detect that the applet in the webbrowser control displays a modal dialog? (alternatively, get a window handle, when a java applet dialog is opening?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sun.plugin2.main.client.ModalityHelper.installModalityListener(). This will signal modalityPopped and modalityPushed.

http://www.javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/plugin2/main/client/ModalityHelper.html#installModalityListener%28sun.plugin2.main.client.ModalityInterface%29

Requires Java 6 and may only work on some specific platforms (scope yet unknown).

Answer (score 0):

Use some JavaScript to directly call the Java method `Window.getWindows()` for an array of existing `Window` objects.  `(J)Frame` objects and `(J)Dialog` objects all extend `Window`.

Note that, AFAIR, each applet gets a `Frame` to contain it.    Because there will be more 'windows' on screen than just dialogs, you'll need to check the types.

Do that at an appropriate interval repeatedly from JS, and it should be possible to detect any dialogs produced by Java applets.

Alternately it might be easier to extend the applet and add some extra methods to make those same checks outlined above, then call a JavaScript to notify that there are dialogs opened.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot control the applets running in the webbrowser - they are produced by other departments and companies (otherwise, I would make the applets call into the winform to display a "real" modal dialog, but thats not what the kids want ;-) ). I would really like not to check at repeated intervals. I was hoping for a signal I could subscribe to..

Comment: *"I was hoping for a signal I could subscribe to.."*  I'm hoping on world peace, and an end to pestilence, drought & famine.

Comment: Nice - can I downvote a comment? ;-) It seems that firefox detects modal dialogs via the message pump. I will try that.

Comment: *"It seems that firefox detects modal dialogs via the message pump. I will try that."*  The .Net 'webbrowser' component is *FF*?!?  Color me stunned.  I felt sure it'd be IE.

Comment: Not the .net webbrowser, but the applets running in firefox.